# Error while packing double byte filenames

Tags: compiler-errors, inno-setup, multibyte

I'm trying to pack some files which names contains korean characters into one installer, using Inno-Setup 5.4.0. When the compiler reach them it prompts an error

> The filename, directory name, or
>   volume syntax is incorrect.

Is there any flag to allow it to read those or some workaround to include those files into the installer?

Comment: Have a look at what the files are called on the command line -- most OSes will make 'safe' names for files with non-ASCII characters. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to work with [Unicode inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=unicode).

From the help:

> Key features of Unicode Inno Setup are its ability to display any language on any system regardless of the system code page, and **its ability to work with Unicode filenames**. One could consider Unicode Inno Setup as the new standard Inno Setup and Non Unicode Inno Setup as an old special Inno Setup for those who still need to support NT/9x or who want the very smallest size possible.

So, make sure you choose the isetup-x.y.z-unicode.exe when downloading (for example **isetup-5.4.0-unicode.exe** to get the current version).